# websocket and nginx error 400

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, nginx, websocket

I am creating websocket on nginx with php backend. But I am get error like this

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://simponi-asn.info:8080/server' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400

This is my nginx config :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;


    root /var/www/simponiasn/html/;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name simponi-asn.info www.simponi-asn.info;
    include hhvm-with-fallback.conf;

ssl on;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;

            proxy_pass http://simponi-asn.info:8080;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;

    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location @fallback {
    #       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #       # With php5-fpm:
           fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
           fastcgi_index index.php;
           include fastcgi_params;

    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
}
```

My js :

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      //ws handler
  //create a new WebSocket object.
 // var wsUri = "ws://localhost:9000/simponi/server";   
 //var wsUri = "ws://192.168.43.47:9000/simponi/server";   
 var wsUri = "ws://simponi-asn.info:8080/server";   
  websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri); 

  websocket.onopen = function(ev) { // connection is open 
   // $('ul.chat').append("<li class=\"system_msg\">Connected!</li>"); //notify user
   var msg = {
    type:'system',
    message: profile.fullname+' Online',
    name: profile.fullname,
    id:profile.id
    };
    //convert and send data to server
    websocket.send(JSON.stringify(msg));
  }

  $('#btn-chat').click(function(){ //use clicks message send button 
    var mymessage = $('#msg').val(); //get message text
    var myname = 'wtf';//$('#name').val(); //get user name


    if(mymessage == ""){ //emtpy message?
      $('#error').text('Pesan tidak boleh kosong.');
      return;
    }

    //prepare json data
    var msg = {
        message: mymessage,
        name: profile.fullname,
        type:'user',
        id:profile.id
    };
    //convert and send data to server
    websocket.send(JSON.stringify(msg));
  });
  //#### Message received from server?
  websocket.onmessage = function(ev) {
    var msg = JSON.parse(ev.data); //PHP sends Json data
    //console.log(msg);
    var type = msg.type; //message type
    var umsg = msg.message; //message text
    var uname = msg.name; //user name

    if(type == 'user') 
    {
      arrow=(msg.id==profile.id?'right':'left');
      $('ul.chat').append('<li class="'+arrow+' clearfix"><span class="chat-img pull-'+arrow+'">\
                            <img src="'+profile.photo+'" alt="User Avatar" class="img-circle" />\
                        </span>\
                            <div class="chat-body clearfix">\
                                <div class="header">\
                                    <strong class="primary-font">'+uname+'</strong> <small class="pull-'+arrow+' text-muted">\
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>12 mins ago</small>\
                                </div>\
                                <p>'+umsg+'</p>\
                            </div>\
                        </li>');
    }
    if(type == 'system')
    {
      $('ul.chat').append("<div li=\"system_msg\">"+umsg+"</li>");
    }

    $('#msg').val(''); //reset text
        $('.panel-body').scrollTop($('.panel-body')[0].scrollHeight);
  };

  websocket.onerror = function(ev){$('ul.chat').append("<li class=\"system_error\">Error Occurred - "+ev.data+"</li>");}; 
  websocket.onclose   = function(ev){$('ul.chat').append("<li class=\"system_msg\">Connection Closed</li>");}; 
  //end ws handler
});
```

My Backend (using CI):

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

require 'basic.php';

class server extends basic {

public $clients = array();

public function __construct()
{
parent::__construct();
session_start();
} 

public function index(){      

    set_time_limit ( 0 );
    $port = '8080';//port
    //$host = 'localhost:9000/simponi/'.__CLASS__; //host
    //$host = '192.168.43.47:9000/simponi/'.__CLASS__; //host
    $host = 'simponi-asn.info:8080/'.__CLASS__; //host
    $null = NULL; //null var

    //Create TCP/IP sream socket
    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
    //reuseable port
    socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);

    //bind socket to specified host
    socket_bind($socket, 0, $port);

    //listen to port
    socket_listen($socket);

    //print_r($socket);

    //create & add listning socket to the list
    $this->clients = array($socket);

    //start endless loop, so that our script doesn't stop
    while (true) {
        //manage multipal connections
        $changed = $this->clients;
        //returns the socket resources in $changed array
        socket_select($changed, $null, $null, 0, 10);

        //check for new socket
        if (in_array($socket, $changed)) {
            $socket_new = socket_accept($socket); //accpet new socket
            $this->clients[] = $socket_new; //add socket to client array

            $header = socket_read($socket_new, 1024); //read data sent by the socket
            //print_r($header);
            $this->perform_handshaking($header, $socket_new, $host, $port); //perform websocket handshake

            socket_getpeername($socket_new, $ip); //get ip address of connected socket

            //get user session data
            //$xxx=$this->session->all_userdata();
        //  print_r($xxx);
            //$response = $this->mask(json_encode(array('type'=>'system', 'message'=>'Online'))); //prepare json data
        //  $this->send_message($response); //notify all users about new connection

            //make room for new socket
            $found_socket = array_search($socket, $changed);
            unset($changed[$found_socket]);
        }

        //loop through all connected sockets
        //if(!empty($changed)){
            foreach ($changed as $changed_socket) { 
                //print_r($changed_socket);
                //check for any incomming data
                while(socket_recv($changed_socket, $buf, 1024, 0) >= 1)
                {
                    $received_text = $this->unmask($buf); //unmask data
                    $msg = json_decode($received_text); //json decode 

                    if(!empty($msg->message)){

                        $user_name = $msg->name; //sender name
                        $user_message = $msg->message; //message text

                        //prepare data to be sent to client
                        $response_text = $this->mask(json_encode(array('type'=>$msg->type, 'id'=>$msg->id, 'name'=>$user_name, 'message'=>$user_message)));
                        $this->send_message($response_text); //send data
                        break 2; //exist this loop
                    }
                }

                $buf = @socket_read($changed_socket, 1024, PHP_NORMAL_READ);
                if ($buf === false) { // check disconnected client
                    // remove client for $this->clients array
                    $found_socket = array_search($changed_socket, $this->clients);
                    socket_getpeername($changed_socket, $ip);
                    unset($this->clients[$found_socket]);

                    //notify all users about disconnected connection
                    $response = $this->mask(json_encode(array('type'=>'system', 'message'=>$ip.' disconnected')));
                    $this->send_message($response);
                }
            }
        //}
    }
    // close the listening socket
    socket_close($socket);
}



private function send_message($msg)
{

    foreach($this->clients as $changed_socket)
    {
        @socket_write($changed_socket,$msg,strlen($msg));
    }
    return true;
}


//Unmask incoming framed message
private function unmask($text) {
    $length = ord($text[1]) & 127;
    if($length == 126) {
        $masks = substr($text, 4, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 8);
    }
    elseif($length == 127) {
        $masks = substr($text, 10, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 14);
    }
    else {
        $masks = substr($text, 2, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 6);
    }
    $text = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($data); ++$i) {
        $text .= $data[$i] ^ $masks[$i%4];
    }
    return $text;
}

//Encode message for transfer to client.
private function mask($text)
{
    $b1 = 0x80 | (0x1 & 0x0f);
    $length = strlen($text);

    if($length <= 125)
        $header = pack('CC', $b1, $length);
    elseif($length > 125 && $length < 65536)
        $header = pack('CCn', $b1, 126, $length);
    elseif($length >= 65536)
        $header = pack('CCNN', $b1, 127, $length);
    return $header.$text;
}

//handshake new client.
private function perform_handshaking($receved_header,$client_conn, $host, $port)
{
    $headers = array();
    //print_r($receved_header);
    $lines = preg_split("/\r\n/", $receved_header);
    foreach($lines as $line)
    {
        $line = chop($line);
        if(preg_match('/\A(\S+): (.*)\z/', $line, $matches))
        {
            $headers[$matches[1]] = $matches[2];
        }
    }
    //print_r($headers);432 
    //if(!empty($headers['Sec-WebSocket-Key'])){
        $secKey = $headers['Sec-WebSocket-Key'];
    //}else{
    //  $secKey=null;
//  }
        //echo $secKey;
    $secAccept = base64_encode(pack('H*', sha1($secKey . '258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11')));
    //hand shaking header
    $upgrade  = "HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake\r\n" .
    "Upgrade: websocket\r\n" .
    "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" .
    "WebSocket-Origin: $host\r\n" .
    "WebSocket-Location: ws://$host:$port/simponi/server\r\n".
    "Sec-WebSocket-Accept:$secAccept\r\n\r\n";
    socket_write($client_conn,$upgrade,strlen($upgrade));
}

}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I doubt your nginx config has anything to do with this since your websocket server is listening on port 8080 for traffic and your nginx server is listening on port 80. You're connecting directly to port 8080. It would not be sensible to assume that any of that traffic is going through your nginx server. You need to check the exception from your ws object and see what the server is responding with. There's not enough information here to even begin guessing what the problem might be.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using nginx at all for dealing with websockets, honestly. Especially not the way you're doing it. For one thing if you do decide to use SSL you can't terminate the SSL at the proxy level using proxypass protocol. You'll need end-to-end encryption and I already see enough wacky things going on in your PHP websocket code that I doubt you'll manage SSL in there. For proxying websockets I'd recommend [HAProxy](http://www.haproxy.org/). For an actual PHP websocket server I'd recommend [auryn](https://github.com/rdlowrey/auryn)

Comment: But __again just to be perfectly clear here__. I doubt this problem has anything at all to do with your nginx config since you are ___clearly not connecting to your websocket server through nginx___.